# Disable navigation on FlipView

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to disable all navigation on my `FlipView` (scrolling horizontally) from user's input (e.g. mouse wheel and touch screen).

The only way the flipview is supposed to change its selected index is programatically, I have already removed the side buttons in the `FlipView`'s style.

I tried changing some of the `ScrollViewer`'s properties in its style but I can't manage to block everything. Anybody can hint me the correct and clean way to do this?

Comment: Put a blank `Grid` on top of it. It will block all user input.

Comment: The thing is, I have controls within the `FlipViewItems` thatI want the user to be able to interact with.

Comment: Try changing the `ManipulationMode` of the FlipView. After that, you can attempt to do things like remove the left and right buttons from the style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution by overriding the `ControlTemplate` and changing `ManipulationMode` in `ItemsPresenter`. Just place this code inside your `FlipView`:

```
<FlipView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPresenter ManipulationMode="None"></ItemsPresenter>
    </ControlTemplate>
</FlipView.Template>
```

In my opinion it shouldn't be that difficult to do something simple like disabling user interaction. There should be a property to do that.

Comment: I just realized that this actually replaces the whole ControlTemplate. The proper way is to inherit the original ControlTemplate to be able to do flipping programatically. Use this custom FlipView style that has ManipulationMode in ItemsPresenter disabled: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/yN8fqa0u)

Answer (score 3):

You can set **IsEnabled** property of the **FlipView** to **False**.

Hope this help!

Comment: This will disable the content of the flipview as well, I just wanted to disable its navigation but allow the user to interact with its content.

Comment: Did you try to put the following code to disable scrollviewer of flipview:

ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"