# UWP FlipView prevent user interactions

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, flipview

Yes, i have googled for it, this solution doesn't do the trick:

[Disable navigation on FlipView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991281/disable-navigation-on-flipview)

Because i want to remain changing items with animations, but only programmatically.

I have investigated the FlipView template and found that all interactions/animations etc. are built using the ScrollingHost by name:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So, i have created a custom class MyFlipView and derivered from FlipView, and overrided MouseWheel ( this gives me the needed behavior on desktop ), and deleted navigation buttons from template ( this also limits user interactions ). But the only thing that remains, user is still able to drag the items by pointer ( tablets, phones, maybe even PC with touch screens ). here is my code:

```
public class MyFlipView : FlipView
{
    ScrollViewer scroll;

    public MyFlipView()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        scroll = GetTemplateChild("ScrollingHost") as ScrollViewer;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        scroll.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        scroll.IsHorizontalRailEnabled = false;
        scroll.IsVerticalRailEnabled = false;
        scroll.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled = false;
        scroll.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled = false;
        scroll.IsHoldingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnPointerWheelChanged(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //base.OnPointerWheelChanged(e);
    }
}
```

**As you can see i tried do disable all the scrolling in the ScrollingHost, but still it is possible to switch items on touchscreens. How can i disable them also?**

Comment: If you only want change programmatically, wouldn't it be easier to just use a ContentPresenter and just change the content? Add an in and out animation and pretty much set... Flip view is designed for that exact purpose, allow the user to navigate trough a collection, you literally want to get rid of all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the FlipView's `IsHitTestVisible` property to false.
Then set `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` to none

Which is basically saying "You can't touch me or tab to me"

Thomas Schneiter's answer would still allow it to be reached via tabbing / other buggy methods of navigation.

Comment: This solution would not let me to use child elements like textboxes etc.

Comment: @Cheese I see, in that case you will have to probably open up the template of the FlipView and gut the parts and bindings inside it that allow physical user input (such as the buttons); then to stop them swiping it left and right with their fingers, you'll have to create a new method for the touch event, and handle it; stopping the control from recieving that kind of input.

Comment: ... or just do it ALL via handling the various interactable events

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any interaction with the FlipView, an easy but... well kinda ugly solution is to put a (almost) transparent rectangle on top of your FlipView.

```
<Grid> 
    <FlipView ... />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0.01" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solution would not let me to use child elements like textboxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Over a year later and still no good solution for disabling FlipView's. Here's what I ended up doing which seems to do the trick without having to create a new FlipView control.

Edit the ControlTemplate and remove all the navigation buttons. Add a transparent background to you DataTemplate container. Add a `PointerWheelChanged` event handler to the DataTemplate container and have it set `e.Handled = true;`. Finally, add a `SelectionChanged` event handler to the FlipView and have it reset the selected item back to the original.

XAML

```
<FlipView x:Name="MyFlipView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items,Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Transparent" PointerWheelChanged="Item_PointerWheelChanged">
                <!--You Item XAML-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <FlipView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
            <Grid>
                <!--Default ScrollViewer settings omitted, but no changes needed-->
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </FlipView.Template>
</FlipView>
```

Code Behind

```cs
private bool _isDisabled;
private object _selectedItem;

public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();

//methods for setting Items, _isDisabled, and _selectedItem omitted

private void Item_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this prevents the wheel from changing the items
    e.Handled = _isDisabled;
}

private void FlipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Can't find a way to disable keyboard from changing items so we'll monitor the change and flip it back
    if (_isDisabled)
    {
        this.SetupSelectedItem();
    }
}

private void SetupSelectedItem()
{
    //do a check here to prevent SelectionChanged events from firing.
    if (this.MyFlipView.SelectedItem != _selectedItem)
    {
        this.MyFlipView.SelectedItem = _selectedItem;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, TouchScreen was still having some problems so I took another stab at it. There are two levels we need to work on, the FlipViewItem and the FlipView. Unfortunately we have to sub-class these because there aren't any overrides we can do to interrupt the default behavior. I also wanted to use binding to be able to turn the flipping on or off. This only supports Horizontal orientation but can easily be adjusted to support Vertical.

Custom FlipViewItem is needed to control the mouse and keyboard.

```cs
public sealed class GalleryFlipViewItem : FlipViewItem
{
    public bool IsFlipEnabled { get; set; }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !this.IsFlipEnabled;

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPointerWheelChanged(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !this.IsFlipEnabled;

        base.OnPointerWheelChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Custom FlipView is needed to control the touch and trickle the setting to the custom FlipViewItem.

```cs
public sealed class GalleryFlipView : FlipView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlipEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsFlipEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(GalleryFlipView), new PropertyMetadata(true, IsFlipEnabledChanged));

    private static void IsFlipEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is GalleryFlipView control)
        {
            if (control.GetTemplateChild("ScrollingHost") is ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
            {
                scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = control.IsFlipEnabled ? ScrollMode.Auto : ScrollMode.Disabled;
            }

            if (control.ContainerFromItem(control.SelectedItem) is GalleryFlipViewItem flipViewItem)
            {
                flipViewItem.IsFlipEnabled = control.IsFlipEnabled;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsFlipEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFlipEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFlipEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new GalleryFlipViewItem
        {
            IsFlipEnabled = this.IsFlipEnabled
        };
    }
}
```

Now we need to add the styles for each of these controls. I just copied the default styles for FlipViewItem and FlipView. I made a small adjustment to the FlipView by removing the up/down buttons and added binding to control the left/right button's visibility. To do this, wrap the original button in a grid and then use a converter to convert the bool to a visibility enum.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsFlipEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}}">
    <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" Width="20" />
</Grid>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsFlipEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}}">
    <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" Width="20" />
</Grid>
```

Since IsFlipEnabled is a DependencyProperty you can use binding, xaml, or code behind to control it.

```
<controls:GalleryFlipView IsFlipEnabled="False">
```

Finally, this seems like the right solution. So frustrating we have to do so much work to simply turn this feature on and off.